On IdentityDbContext vs AspNetSqlMembershipProvider: How to solve coexistence of webforms and web api technologies?
Being quite new to ASP.NET Core and Web API (Microsoft solution), I need to use the authentication and authorization for the Web API where the users and roles are maintained using the older ASP.NET WebForms application.
The ASP.NET WebForms application uses the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider to access the the older type of the authentication database. The ASP.NET Core Web API uses the EntityFramework, and its IdentityDbContext class to wrap the newer form of the authentication database.
The Web API project is in alpha/beta phase of development -- the authentication and authorization just to be added. The ASP.NET WebForms application is currently used by many users, and I would like to keep it as is (for stability reasons).
What could be the ways of sharing the existing user credentials and roles?

Can the older database form (as accessed by the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider) be wrapped somehow by the IdentityDbContext for reading?
Or can the older authentication database be migrated (with the content) from the older database to the newer one, and then can the ASP.NET WebForms application be modified to use another membership provider to use the newer database?
Or can the older authentication database be somehow mirrored into the newer authentication database so that the two databases would keep the same content and the older application would read/write to the older database, and the newer Web API application would read-only from the newer database?

I am in the phase when I do not know what is the "good question" for stating the problem. So, I do not want to be too explicit/precise when forming the question as there may be some "surprisingly simpler" approach that I do not know about.
Update 12. 12. 2024: The original WebForms application and the Web API application should access the same application database. That is the WebForms application presents the application data as forms, the Web API application will present the same data as JSON data to the caller (the mobile application that uses a different presenting technology) -- the same user should get the same subset of the data based on his/her login, role, and other settings. The other settings are stored in the application database (no problem here). However, the login and the roles are stored in the authentication database, and the shape of the authentication database differs for the two technologies. In other words, finally, the authentication database should be shared by both WebForms application and Web API application. So, the question probably is how to access the old-technology authentication database (login, roles) by the Web API (ASP.NET Core).
The Web API runs on the same IIS server, but it has a different root URL.

Your question is currently unclear. How are the ASP.NET Webforms application and the ASP.NET Core WebAPI application related to each other here? Are you wanting the Webforms application to use the new ASP.NET Core WebAPI for API calls?

@TylerH: Thanks for the response. I have added the Update to explain.

Thanks for the update. It sounds like you are best served by using something like a SQL Server database for all the application data including security access. You can have effectively infinite number of applications using any kind of technologies accessing a single SQL database, so if there is no direct interaction between the Webforms application and the WebAPI (other than sharing a database or user access), then you probably don't need to do anything special to get them to work together.

If your question is instead how to use an existing SQL database table to manage user access for an ASP.NET Core WebAPI, there may well be a question (or multiple) here that address that: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+link+ASP.NET+Core+WebAPI+usage+permissions+to+a+SQL+database+site:stackoverflow.com&sca_esv=fa27aa6c1a2c9000&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiknMHa3KKKAxUP58kDHZ-1B5oQrQIoBHoECCcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=926&dpr=1

General concerns would be how you determine whether someone has access to one form or the other. Your user permissions table would need a column for the WebAPI as well as the old app, if access is handled separately (e.g., if some users can have access to one but not the other). This may require dropping the table to add a column depending on your constraints/database design, or you may be able to modify it without dropping and recreating it. If you end up adding a column, you'll need to make sure your Webforms app code can handle writing data to the table now that it has a new column.

Well, it not clear why you don't just add some API end points to the existing WebForms application?
In other words, adding some web methods to existing pages, or even adding a .asmx web service page to the existing WebForms would be the easiest road.
However, assuming that both web sites have full rights and access to the same database?
Then change the security SQL provider and the role provider for the WebForms to point to the same "user" database as the new site. This will require you to add (create) these two providers for the existing web forms site.
It is rather easy to simply "inherit" the SqlProvider, and "inhert" the RoleProvider in the existing Webforms application, and that will THEN allow you to point the user database to the new and SAME user database in the new site with the API's.
So, in terms of most easy?
I would consider just adding the API's (web end points) to the existing application. In fact the big question why this was not considered a option? As I pointed out, little or next to nothing is and would prevent you from adding web end points (API's) to the existing site. As noted, this not only solves all your issues, but web end points for WebForms automatic support REST, XML and JSON data, and do so without any special efforts on your part.
If above is not a valid choice (and you not explained why this easy road is not being taken), then next up would be to simply point the existing WebForms's SqlProvider, and RoleProvider's to the new database. You can as noted, create a new (custom) SqlProvider, and a new RoleProvider. If you inherit the existing providers, you find that very few code stubs are required for both of these providers to continue to work, and work by being pointed to the new user database.
Of course, the only issue I can see is if you're using some of the older "legacy" pages often provided in WebForms to add new users, delete (disable) new users, and how they do things like re-set their password etc.
And how now are these users assigned security roles for the existing site? In other words, how many moving parts are being used to manage existing users? (either none, or a lot??? - this question needs to be answered). In other words, how much "legacy" management pages are being used to manage, create, and do things like re-set passwords? That code needs to be looked at, since in some cases they "high" make use of the built in SQL and Role providers for security. Knowledge of this aspect would determine if it is far better to simply start adding some API's to the existing application in place of creating a whole new project. As I stated, why not just add some API's to the existing application? Are you REALLY having to add that many API's and end points to the point that warrants a whole new application? I mean, if you only are going to have say 5 or 10 new API's (end points), then why not just add them to the existing application and you now all done?
So, much of this will come down to how the existing code manages user logon's, password re-sets etc. If application has existing custom pages for this purpose, then this suggests creating a new Role and SQL provider for security. A custom sql and role provider would be little work, and that would result in the WebForms site now using the new user database that the API site is using. However, this "easy" will depend on if existing "legacy" IIS management is being used to manage users. And the reason why this matters then you have to spend more time re-creating the SQL and Role provider's (since then, MORE then just a few of the SQL/Role provider routines will have been used to manage user's on that site, and thus you have to write more code, or better stated, support more of the SQL/Role providers interface code).
As noted, my first choice and suggestion would be to add the web end point's and API's to the existing WebForms application, and it not at all clear why this was or is not the first choice?
